# brackets and text should start at the same postion

Tags: formatting

I have the following document:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Heizk{\"o}rper}  \\
 $\rightarrow$ \text{ modelliert als beliebig oft unterbrechbare hybride Ger{\"a}te} $J^{HK}$ \\

    W{\"a}rmeleistung $PW^{HK}$


    \begin{equation*}
PW^{HK}_j(t)  = 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{lr@{}l}
hl_{Standyby} & \text{f"ur  }&  t < r_j +  s_{j,1}   \\
hl_{j,Run}^{a} (t_{r,l}) & \text{f"ur  } &  r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
      + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l-1} p^a_{j,i} + (l-1) * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non}
      \leq t \leq  r_j \\
      && + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i} +\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non}\\
hl_{Standyby} & \text{f"ur  }  & r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
     + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non} 
     < t <  r_j \\
     &&+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l+1} s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + l * p_{j,non}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

Warmwasserbedarf $W_j$

\begin{equation*}
W_j (t)  = 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{lr@{}l}
0 & \text{f"ur  }&  t < r_j +  s_{j,1}   \\
w_{j,Run}^{a} (t_{r,l}) & \text{f"ur  } &  r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
      + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l-1} p^a_{j,i} + (l-1) * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non}
      \leq t \leq  r_j \\
      && + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i} +\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non}\\
0 & \text{f"ur  }  & r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
     + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non} 
     < t <  r_j \\
     &&+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l+1} s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + l * p_{j,non}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}



mit

  \begin{align*}
     &l \in \left\{1, 2, \dots , n\right\} \text{ n ist Entscheidungsvariable } \\
    &p^a_{j,l} \text{ mit } l \in \{1,2, ... , n\} \text{ sind n Entscheidungsvariablen } \\
    t_{r,l} &= t - r_j - \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i} - \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l-1} p_{j,i}^a - (l-1) * p_{j,min} - (l-1) * p_{j,non} \\
    \end{align*}
und 
    \begin{align*}
    a \in \{1,2, ... , k\} &\quad  a \text{ sind  zus{\"a}tzliche Entscheidungsvariablen} \\
    w_{j,l}^{1},w_{j,l}^{2}, ... , w_{j,l}^{k} &:  k \text{  verschiedene Profile f{\"u}r alle Phasen } l \quad \forall j \in J^{HK} \\
    &l \in \{1,2, ... , n\} \\
    \end{align*}





\end{document}
```

In this document I have two main forumulars PW(t) and W(t) and I want their brackets to start at the same positon such that they are underneath each other (same horizontal position).
Furthermore I want the words "Warmeleistung", "Warmwasserbedarf", "mit" and "und" to start at the same horizontal position. How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 3):

May be this? Using `\intertext` and all inside `{align*}`. I used `gather` in the last group since there's no clear alignment. And left no space before “mit” so it's on the left margin without being indented.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Heizk{\"o}rper}  \\
 $\rightarrow$ \text{ modelliert als beliebig oft unterbrechbare hybride Ger{\"a}te} $J^{HK}$ \\

    W{\"a}rmeleistung $PW^{HK}$


    \begin{align*}
PW^{HK}_j(t)  &= 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{lr@{}l}
hl_{Standyby} & \text{f"ur  }&  t < r_j +  s_{j,1}   \\
hl_{j,Run}^{a} (t_{r,l}) & \text{f"ur  } &  r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
      + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l-1} p^a_{j,i} + (l-1) * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non}
      \leq t \leq  r_j \\
      && + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i} +\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non}\\
hl_{Standyby} & \text{f"ur  }  & r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
     + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non} 
     < t <  r_j \\
     &&+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l+1} s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + l * p_{j,non}
\end{array}\right. \\
\intertext{Warmwasserbedarf $W_j$}
W_j (t)  &= 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{lr@{}l}
0 & \text{f"ur  }&  t < r_j +  s_{j,1}   \\
w_{j,Run}^{a} (t_{r,l}) & \text{f"ur  } &  r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
      + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l-1} p^a_{j,i} + (l-1) * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non}
      \leq t \leq  r_j \\
      && + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i} +\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non}\\
0 & \text{f"ur  }  & r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
     + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + (l-1) * p_{j,non} 
     < t <  r_j \\
     &&+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l+1} s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,min} + l * p_{j,non}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
mit
  \begin{gather*}
     l \in \left\{1, 2, \dots , n\right\} \text{ n ist Entscheidungsvariable } \\
    p^a_{j,l} \text{ mit } l \in \{1,2, ... , n\} \text{ sind n Entscheidungsvariablen } \\
    t_{r,l} = t - r_j - \sum \limits_{i=1}^l s_{j,i} - \sum \limits_{i=1}^{l-1} p_{j,i}^a - (l-1) * p_{j,min} - (l-1) * p_{j,non} \\
\intertext{und }
    a \in \{1,2, ... , k\} \quad  a \text{ sind  zus{\"a}tzliche Entscheidungsvariablen} \\
    w_{j,l}^{1},w_{j,l}^{2}, ... , w_{j,l}^{k} :  k \text{  verschiedene Profile f{\"u}r alle Phasen } l \quad \forall j \in J^{HK} \\
    l \in \{1,2, ... , n\} \\
    \end{gather*}





\end{document}
```

Comment: You should also fix the wrong usages of ``\\`` and of blank lines before `align`

Comment: And probably other things: `array` to `cases`, `_{text}` to `_{\mathrm{text}}`, `\sum\limits` to `\sum`, `\left\{ .. \right\}` to `\{ .. \}`, `\noindent`, `\underline`, ``\\`` outside math/array/tabular, `...` to `\dots`, may be `l` to `\ell`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably better introduce some abbreviations for avoiding such long formulas with repeated terms.

The alignment can be obtained by `\intertext`, but there are also several improvements that can be made.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\underline{Heizk{\"o}rper}  \\
$\rightarrow$ modelliert als beliebig oft unterbrechbare hybride Ger{\"a}te $J^{HK}$

\noindent
W{\"a}rmeleistung $PW^{HK}$
\begin{align*}
PW^{HK}_j(t)  &=
\begin{dcases}
hl_{\mathrm{Standby}} &
  \text{f"ur } t < r_j +  s_{j,1}   \\
hl_{j,\mathrm{Run}}^{a} (t_{r,l}) &
  \text{f"ur }
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  r_j &+ \sum_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
       + \sum_{i=1}^{l-1} p^a_{j,i} + (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} + (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{non}}
      \\
      &+ \sum _{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
       + \sum_{i=1}^{k} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} + (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{non}}
       \leq t \leq  r_j
  \end{aligned}\\
hl_{\mathrm{Standby}} &
  \text{f"ur }
  \begin{aligned}[t]
   r_j &+ \sum_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
        + \sum_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} + (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{non}} 
        \\
       &+ \sum_{i=1}^{l+1} s_{j,i}
        + \sum_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} + l * p_{j,\mathrm{non}}
        < t <  r_j
  \end{aligned}
  \end{dcases}\\
\intertext{Warmwasserbedarf $W_j$}
W_j (t)  &= 
\begin{dcases}
0 &
  \text{f"ur } t < r_j +  s_{j,1}   \\
w_{j,\mathrm{Run}}^{a} (t_{r,l}) &
  \text{f"ur }
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  r_j &+ \sum_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
       + \sum_{i=1}^{l-1} p^a_{j,i} + (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} + (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{non}}
      \\
      &+ \sum_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
       +\sum_{i=1}^{k} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} + (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{non}}
       \leq t \leq  r_j
  \end{aligned}\\
0 &
  \text{f"ur }
  \begin{aligned}[t]
   r_j &+ \sum_{i=1}^l s_{j,i}
        + \sum_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} + (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{non}}
       \\
       &+ \sum_{i=1}^{l+1} s_{j,i}
        + \sum_{i=1}^{l} p^a_{j,i} + l * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} + l * p_{j,\mathrm{non}}
        < t <  r_j
  \end{aligned}
\end{dcases}
\end{align*}
mit
\begin{align*}
  & l \in \{1, 2, \dots , n\},\text{ $n$ ist Entscheidungsvariable} \\
  & p^a_{j,l}, \text{ mit } l \in \{1,2,\dots,n\} \text{ sind $n$ Entscheidungsvariablen} \\
  & t_{r,l} = t - r_j - \sum_{i=1}^l s_{j,i} - 
    \sum_{i=1}^{l-1} p_{j,i}^a - (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{min}} - (l-1) * p_{j,\mathrm{non}} \\
\intertext{und}
  & a \in \{1,2, \dots , k\}, \text{ $a$ sind  zus{\"a}tzliche Entscheidungsvariablen} \\
  & w_{j,l}^{1},w_{j,l}^{2}, \dots, w_{j,l}^{k}, \text{ $k$ verschiedene Profile f{\"u}r alle Phasen } l\\
  & \forall j \in J^{HK}, l \in \{1,2,\dots , n\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be a perfectionist, there's the `\!` necessary before `\begin{(align|gather|multlin)ed}`.